# Filtering for close dates in the next 30 days based on current date in R

Tags: r, date

I am having an issue filtering for dates only in the next 30 days based on todays date in R. The close date column I want to filter on is already set to a date type and is in the format `Year-Month-Day` (2022-06-22).

I want to be able to use records that have a close date of the next 30 days from today's date.

```r
x_data %>% filter(CloseDate > today())
```

This only shows anything greater than todays date, but I want it to be specific to only the next 30 days from today.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a second condition to your `dplyr::filter()` like

```
x_date %>% filter(CloseDate > today() & CloseDate <= today() + 30)
```

Comment: @tivd- thank you! Curveball- I just noticed there are some deals with past "close dates." Is it possible to have a "safe catch" look back period too? Meaning, not only 30 days ahead, but 30 days back too so I can view what deals missed the mark?

Comment: @Edmonds15 Yes, if you use `filter(CloseDate >=  today() - 30 & CloseDate <= today() + 30)` you will get the full 60-day period.